# how do i make a ceaser cipher where the letter "z" becomes "a" on +1 shift in python

Tags: python

How do I shift the end of the alphabet so "z" becomes "a"?

i was thinking a if statement

```
plaintext = input("please type message:")

def split(plaintext):
    return list(plaintext)
print(split(plaintext))

for s in plaintext:
    a = ord(s)
    print (a)
list1=[]
for t in plaintext:
    b = ord(t)
    c = b+1
    print (c)
    list1.append(c)
print (list1)
aa =""
for ab in list1:
    aa = aa + chr(ab)
print (str(aa))
print(split(aa))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to increase the character by one you could do this:

```
def inc_chr(c):
    return chr((ord(c) + 1 - ord("a")) % 26 + ord("a"))
```

test:

```
for char in "abcxyz":
    print(f"{char} {inc_chr(char)}")
```

outputs:

```
a b
b c
c d
x y
y z
z a
```

basically you do calculations modulo 26 with an offset of `ord("a") = 97`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a look up dict and convert the characters.

```
import string
alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase
look_up = {alphabets[i]: alphabets[i-1] for i in range(len(alphabets))}
```

You can then use this lookup for cypher

```
test = "This will be encoded"
out = = "".join([look_up.get(char, char) for char in test])
print(out)
```